# Serialising into JSON a Backbone collection which contains attributes

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I would like to know how exactly a serialisation into JSON of a Backbone collection which contains attributes and models could be performed.

So per example if I have a collection like this:

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   initialize: function (attr, options) {
      this.property = options.property;
   } 
});
```

When trying to stringify with the JSON.stringify(myCollection) function, the stringify will call the object toJSON method defined in the Backbone Collection Object. Backbone collection defines this method as follows:

```
toJSON : function() {
   return this.map(function(model){ return model.toJSON(); });
}
```

This means that only the models included in the collection will be included in the result JSON object but not the attributes of the collection I previously defined.

Do you know who this could be achieved?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Maybe not clear enough in my original question, I know I could override the toJSON method my questions is how exactly do it to achieve what I need in a general matter (not only for this specific attribute but imagine I have another collections which contains other properties, and all of them inherit from a baseCollection object. More over I would like to know how to restore that JSON object back to the backbone original state (not sure if by creating a new collection passing the JSON object in the parameters of the constructor would do the trick with this attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You could override the "toJSON" method in your MyCollection class and return the string that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `toJSON` method like @trunal-bhanse said, but if your goal is to sync that data with your server then you should probably find a better way of representing that data. Backbone Collections by default return an array when you call `toJSON` on an instance of one. That array then gets converted into a string using `JSON.stringify` before being sent to the server. However, the `JSON.stringify` method will not include any properties you've set on the array:

```
var test = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
test.Hello = "World!";
console.log(test);    //  ["foo", "bar", "baz", Hello: "World!"]
JSON.stringify(test); // '["foo", "bar", "baz"]'
```

Comment: In this case I dont want to save it on the server but temporary save it in localstorage. What you described is the problem I exposed and I am not sure how exactly to override the toJSON method to accomplish what I need.

Comment: @JavierTarazaga saving it to `localStorage` won't do you any good either unless you also plan on overriding the `JSON.parse` method. Even if you overwrote the `toJSON` method on the collection and managed to store an invalid JSON string to `localStorage` you'd still have the problem of *retrieving* and parsing that string later.